# SSL error when connecting iot device to iot edge device

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I am trying to send message from iot device to iot hub through iot edge gateway. The iot edge gateway uses self signed certificate. Although I have added root CA certificate to iot device, I always get error that it can not verify certificate. Please help advise how I can disable certificate verification.
Code: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/main/samples/async-edge-scenarios/send_message_downstream.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/iot/device/common/mqtt_transport.py", line 396, in connect
    rc = self._mqtt_client.connect(
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 914, in connect
    return self.reconnect()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1073, in reconnect
    sock.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/iot/device/iothub/aio/async_clients.py", line 33, in handle_result
    return await callback.completion()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/iot/device/common/async_adapter.py", line 91, in completion
    return await self.future
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/iot/device/common/pipeline/pipeline_stages_mqtt.py", line 206, in _run_op
    self.transport.connect(password=password)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/iot/device/common/mqtt_transport.py", line 409, in connect
    raise exceptions.TlsExchangeAuthError() from e
azure.iot.device.common.transport_exceptions.TlsExchangeAuthError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/connect.py", line 54, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/pi/connect.py", line 35, in main
    await device_client.connect()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/iot/device/aio/patch_documentation.py", line 14, in connect
    return await super(IoTHubDeviceClient, self).connect()
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/iot/device/iothub/aio/async_clients.py", line 231, in connect
    await handle_result(callback)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/azure/iot/device/iothub/aio/async_clients.py", line 45, in handle_result
    raise exceptions.ClientError("Error in the IoTHub client due to TLS exchanges.") from e
azure.iot.device.exceptions.ClientError: Error in the IoTHub client due to TLS exchanges.
```

I tried to look for a way to disable certificate verification but I can not find out

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to disable the certificate verification - it's required for a downstream device to connect to an IoT Edge gateway.

Did you configure the gateway with the certificate by editing the config.toml file? For more information, see https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/iot-edge/how-to-create-transparent-gateway?view=iotedge-1.4&tabs=iotedge#configure-certificates-on-device

Comment: Yes, I have edit these lines accordingly but it does not help:
Find the trust_bundle_cert parameter. Uncomment this line and provide the file URI to the root CA certificate file on your device.

Find the [edge_ca] section of the file. Uncomment the three lines in this section and provide the file URIs to your certificate and key files as values for the following properties:

cert: device CA certificate
pk: device CA private key